# Getting "Token Error: Bad Request" while invoking callback URL

Tags: javascript, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am getting the following whenever I invoke the callback URL using google-Oauth2.

**Error traceback:**

```
TokenError: Bad Request
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:358:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:405:16)
    at G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:175:45
    at G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (G:\projects\oauth\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**GoogleStrategy:**

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
    //options for the gooogle strategy

        clientID: keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
        callbackURL:"http://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect",

    },(accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done) => {
        // Check if user exist in our database
        User.findOne({googleId: profile.id}).then((currentUser)=>{
            if(currentUser){
                // already have the user
                console.log('user is ', currentUser);
                done(null,currrentUser);
            }else{
                // if not create a user in db
                new User({
                    username: profile.displayName,
                    googleId: profile.id 
                  }).save().then((newUser) =>{
                     console.log('new user created' , newUser);
                     done(null,newUser);
                  });
            }
        })



    })
);
```

**Callback Routes:**

```
 //auth with google 
    router.get('/google',passport.authenticate('google',{
        scope:['profile']
    }));

    //callback for google to redirect to
    router.get('/google/redirect',passport.authenticate('google'),(req,res) =>{
        //res.send(req.user);
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

I am new in this field. Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

u have to use **passport.serializeUser** and call the done method in it,
also use **passport.initialize method as middleware** on the routes that u are using **passport.authenticate** in it
had the same problem this worked for me